# Detect if a table contains a column in Android/sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, pragma

So I have an app on the market, and with an update I want to add some columns to the database. No problems so far. But I want to detect if the database in use is missing these columns, and add them if this is the case. I need this to be done dynamically and not just after the update to the new version, because the application is supposed to still be able to import older databases. Normally I would be able to use the [PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) query, but Im not sure how to do this with Android. I cant use execSQL since it is a query, and I cant figure out how to use PRAGMA with the query()-function.

Ofcourse I could just catch exceptions and then add the column, or always add the columns to each table before I start to work with it, but that is not a neat solution.

Cheers,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pragma works. As an example I just tried it on one of my Android App DBs.

```
sqlite> pragma table_info (userCommand);

cid name        type    notnull     dflt_value  pk
0   id      INTEGER     0       1
1   description TEXT    0       0
2   message     TEXT    0       0
```

As we can see there are three fields in the specified table. id, description, and message.

So in your app, use something like:

```
Cursor c = null;
c = RawQuery ("pragma table_info (userCommand)",null); 
// if c has records and is not null then iterate through the records in search of your table name.
```

Please excuse the poor formatting.

Answer (score 3):

This may be overkill, but you can select a single row from your table into a Cursor and use Cursor.getColumnIndex([column name as string]).  This will return -1 if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `PRAGMA` with `rawQuery()` instead of `query()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could issue the following command and go over the results and see if your column is listed.

```
pragma table_info(table_name);
```

**Edit:** I've never done this on Android, but I think it should work

Comment: My bad. Like I said. Not tried it on Android. Try CommonsWare's suggestions regarding rawQuery.