# How to check data your storage?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences

We usually use *SharedPreference* and *SQLite DB* to storage some cache data.
But now many Android Devices don't allow you to see the data in *root partition/data/...*

How to check these ones?

Comment: for the SQLite I'm using the sqlite3, for the SharedPreference I didn't try yet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364577/how-to-get-the-current-sqlite-database-size-or-package-size-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you'd need root access, or at least runtime permissions to read the storage since Android 23

You can use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to inspect such information.

If you only care about seeing the filesystem, Android DDMS is built in to Android Studio, and does let you inspect the filesystem