# How to get the current SQLite database size of an attached database?

Tags: sqlite

With an SQLite database, I know I can do this to get the current size of the main database:

```
SELECT page_count * page_size as size FROM pragma_page_count(), pragma_page_size();
```

See also here ([How to get the current sqlite database size or package size in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364577/how-to-get-the-current-sqlite-database-size-or-package-size-in-android))

But how would I get the size of an **attached** database ?

In my case I have 'main' and an attached database 'db2' (`ATTACH DATABASE 'something.db' as db2;`) and I tried this:

```
SELECT page_count * page_size as size FROM db2.pragma_page_count(), db2.pragma_page_size();
```

but it just returns 0, even though I know something is there.

It's easy to find documentation on `PRAGMA page_count;` but I couldn't find much on `pragma_page_count()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are user valued functions try sending the schema name as an argument (instead of a prefix).

Comment: Ah I found it:  SELECT page_count * page_size as size FROM pragma_page_count('db2'), pragma_page_size('db2');